# Team Foundation Server and ability to copy dashboards to another project

Tags: tfs, dashboard

I'm using Team Foundation Server 2017 express edition. My question is related with dashboards. Is there any possibility to change default dashboard or copy dashboard from another project. It's very time-consuming to configure dashboard for every new project.

I'll be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the feature copy dashboard is not supported for now.

And there is already a **[user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/15008376-ability-to-copy-tfs-dashboards)** submitted to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to push Dev team to achieve that in future release.

And there is an Extension : [VSTS Copy Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=canarysautomationspvtltd.dashboardmigratortool), but unfortunately it's only available for VSTS.

To manage the dashboard you can refer to this link for details : [Add and manage dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/dashboards).

Comment: Two years later: no solution from Microsoft yet... unbelievable. The user voice you posted was simply deleted from their forums, that is what I call "commitment to the customer".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rest api.  Do a GET, edit the result, and then do a put for a new db